# How to change object during LWC wire - pulling multiple variables

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-object, lwc-wire-adapter, wire

I need to pull out data from wire method which returns 3 objects. List, and two Sets: Set based on delievered id parameter. I need list of contacts returned with changed properties to Value and Label and original properties are id and name, but when I try to do that variable shows me as undefined value. Does anyone have some idea?

```
contacts;
departments;
tags;

 @wire(getAdditionalData, { Id: '12345' })
    wired({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            console.log('error', error);
        }
        else if (data) {            
            this.tags = Object.keys(data.tags).map(function(key){
                return {label: data.tags[key], value: data.tags[key]}
            });

            this.departments = Object.keys(data.departments).map(function(key){
                return {label: data.departments[key], value: data.departments[key]}
            });

            for (let i = 0; i < data[i].contacts.length; i++) {
                 let obj = { value: data[i].Id, label: data[i].Name };
//here if i console log obj it shows proper values
                this.contacts.push(obj);  //but here it gets undefined
                return this.contacts;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
I actually think that what is more likely is that your `for` loop is not working properly.

Probably the best option is to use a `forEach` loop

```
//push to intermediate object to make binding more efficient
let tempContacts = [];
data.contacts.forEach( contact => {
  tempContacts.push({ value: contact.Id, label: contact.Name })
});
this.contacts = tempContacts;
```

**Previous**:

I think you need to declare `this.contacts` as an `Array` before you can push to it.

Push is an `Array.prototype` method, so if your variable is not an array, it won't have `push` defined.

So do this:

```
contacts = [];
```

Also, I don't think you need to return anything in the wire method - it's not a promise or an inner function. I think you can just remove the line:

```
return this.contacts;
```

Comment: I have tried to do exactly as You said before but it throws just the same error:

[LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Cannot read property 'push' of undefined]]

Comment: Hmm, I think it's actually this that's the problem `for (let i = 0; i < data[i].contacts.length; i++) {` - I'll come back to later. However, try making it: `data.contacts.length` - you can't use the iterator inside the iteration definition. Even better - use a `forEach`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank You Caspar! :)